# Clarification of error in Taylor polynomial

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I don't understand where the $t\geq49$ comes from (problem 10), circled in the answer.
[image]

[image]

Comment: note that $49$ is the square less than $64$

Comment: Square of what, do you mean?

Comment: I mean it's the square of an integer; we know its square root, so we can plug it in to the formulas

Comment: Yes, 49 is the square of 7, but what's the motivation for "plugging it into the formula"? Is it due to $\sqrt(61) \approx 7.8103027$?

Comment: we want to bound the error on an interval [$x$ , $64$] containing $61$; $64=8^2,$ so $x=7^2$ is the closest convenient choice